# Hangfire alternative for Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, hangfire, background-task

Is there a background job service similar to Hangfire but for Xamarin Android?
What I need is a framework that allows you to enqueue tasks to be ran in background but also can resume after the application is closed and opened again.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) and [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) for background jobs support in Android.

Comment: What would it be the alternative for xamarin forms ?